# How to convert comma separated Query param into KeyValue Pair json object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this Query param that I already converted into JSON.

{"Id":"ZX0123455555,ZX0123455555,ZX0123455545"}

And I want it to become looks like this:

{
"Id": "ZX0123455555",
"Id": "ZX0123455555",
"Id": "ZX0123455545"
}

Just to simplify my JSon schema validation. Thanks

Comment: You cant have the same key repeated multiple times in an object.

Comment: Your desired result is not valid json, because you can't have multiple properties with the same key

Comment: you cannot have the same repeated key for the JSON object. you may have multiple objects inside the JSON but what you are trying to create is a wrong JSON

Comment: `id` could be an array of strings. `{ "id": ["ZX0123455555", "ZX0123455555", "ZX0123455545"] }`.

Comment: make it an array instead

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for correcting me and to your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have an object with the same keys and multiply values but you can have this array:

```js
const myObject = {"Id":"ZX0123455555,ZX0123455555,ZX0123455545"};

const  myArray = myObject.Id.split(',')
const newArray = myArray.map((e)=>{return {Id:e}})

console.log(newArray)
```